# Setting DC-bias on LVDS receiver with internal 100ohm differential termination

Tags: lvds

Here is the setup :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faK1ku.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

RX channel is routed as 100ohm controlled impedance. FPGA input pins are LVDS IOs. I want to apply a DC bias of +1.2V at the FPGA. can I simply add 50ohm pull-ups to +1.2V on each of the differential lines? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the internal termination, you could externally terminate to 1.2V / 50 ohms on each input.  However, with internal 100 ohm termination enabled, you should use much higher value resistors to set the common mode voltage as shown below from [this Maxim app note](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4085).  The larger resistors set the common mode voltage, but do not interfere with the termination.

Your signal integrity should be a little better with internal termination, so the higher value external resistors are probably the best solution.

[image]

Comment: Excellent...that makes sense. Thanks crj11!